# Javascript converting object to string

Tags: javascript, java, json, string, servlets

On the server side, I'm sending an array of Strings using a Java servlet.

On the response tab, I see the data properly.

On the network tab, under response header, I see expected output as:

```
["John","James","steve"].
```

However, in the console, when I try to print the response variable, I see it as:

```
[ e { 0="J",  1="o",  2="h",  more...},e { 0="J",  1="a",  2="m",  more...},e { 0="s",  1="t",  2="e",  more...}]
```

How can I print it as  `["John","James","steve"]` efficiently?

Assuming the response array is in variable response, I tried:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(response[0])
console.log(respponse[0]);
console.log(response[0].toString());
```

None printed the word `"John"`.

Comment: Ensure the servlet is returning the application type json.

Comment: Due to other reasons I can't use return type as Json... I can use any return type other than json

Comment: JSON.parse(response)

Comment: @javaMan You'll need to parse the response, then.

Comment: @Burrito JSON.parse didn't work... I got SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: @DaveNewton Bruteforce way is to read char by char and compile to string... I thought JS has a better solution to render it as string.. what do you mean by parsing

Comment: @javaMan ... Using... `.parse` as Burrito said? You have to have a valid JSON string in order to parse JSON. If you can't send back valid JSON you'll have to play with it on the JS side. OTOH, if you can't send back valid JSON you're working under some pretty bizarre constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to create a Json string on the Servlet side

```
response.getWriter().append("{[\"John\":\"James\"]}")
```

Comment: '["John","James","steve"]' is a valid json array

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand your point, I suppose that you mean that you got an array with several objects, which looks like:

```
var output = [{ 0: "J", 1: "o", 2: "h", 3: "n" },
              { 0: "J", 1: "a", 2: "m", 3: "e", 4: "s" }, 
              { 0: "S", 1: "t", 2: "e", 3: "v", 4: "e" }
             ];
```

So if you can't do it on **server** side, you can do it using JavaScript like:

```
var names = [];

output.forEach(function(name) {
  var con = [];
  for (key in name) {
    if (name.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      con[+key] = name[key];
    }
  }
  names.push(con.join(''));
});

console.log(names);
```

And `names` array will be like:

```
[ 'John', 'James', 'Steve' ]
```